# Delete blank pages in the introductory part of thesis document (yathesis document class)

Tags: yathesis

Bonjour. Mon encadrant souhaiterai faire disparaître des pages présentes en partie liminaire. J'ai regardé dans la documentation `yathesis` mais il semblerait que cela ne soit pas en option. Y a t-il un moyen de le faire en modifiant la classe `yathesis`?

My supervisor would like me to remove blank pages in the introductory. I looked in the `yathesis` documentation but it seems that this is not an option. Is there a way to do this by modifying the `yathesis` LaTeX class?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I've gone ahead and added an English-translation of your posting, as English is definitely the main language on this site.

Comment: just don't use commands like `\makedisclaimer,\makelaboratory...` and then use  `\documentclass[...,noerror=true]{yathesis}`

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is one way of doing it. However to keep the pages generated by \makelaboratory, they should not be deleted, in which case the "oneside" option should be applied in the document class

\documentclass[...,oneside]{yathesisedit}